# Разное отображение колонок Bootstrap'a на компьютере и телефоне

Tags: bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Почему при адаптивной вёрстке посредством бутсрапа, при одинаковом расширении экрана колонки отображаются по разному. Вот два фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первое с телефона второе с компьютера (при том же расширении что и у телефона).
атрибуты дива прописаны так "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6". Где я опять туплю, знатоки направьте на путь истинный...

Comment: в head добавлен? - <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1" />

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"> добавлено без максимум скэйл, ну это не критично же.

Comment: Можете добавить в вопрос HTML и CSS вашей страницы? Или дать ссылку на неё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPD. Ширина элементов

На странице полно элементов, не помещающихся на мобильнике по ширине.

1) Слайдер в начале страницы:

```
<div class="slider-nav slick-slide slick-cloned" style="width: 585px;" data-slick-index="-1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">

.slider-nav img { 
    width: 580px;

@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
.slider-for {
    width: 585px;
```

2) Списки лучших:

```
.goalscores, .assistants {
    width: 600px;

.list-gs, .list-as {
    width: 600px;
```

3) Комментарии:

```
.layout-comment {
  width: 500px;
```

4) Копирайт и мейл для обратной связи не помещаются в своей колонке (на экране мобильного она для них слишком узка):

```
<div class="feedback">Обратная связь: <a href="mailto:redactor@eurocups.ru">redactor@eurocups.ru</a></div>

<p class="copyright">© UEFACups.RU 2016</p>
```

Задайте нужную ширину через медиа-запрос. Переставьте на узком экране копирайт и обратную связь под футер. Уберите ширину слайдера из HTML.

---

### Таблицы

Похоже, в вашем макете две таблицы. У бутстрапа таблицы легко выходят за край экрана.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
</table>
```

Заверните таблицы в блок с классом `table-responsive`, и бутстрап добавит к ним [горизонтальную полосу прокрутки](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

PS. Вместо `col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6` можно использовать просто `col-md-6`. Получится ровно то же самое: начиная с 992px колонка будет занимать 50% ширины контейнера, а до этого будет растягиваться на все 100%.

Comment: Извините, не лечит. Что странно, так это то, что вот таким образом делится весь сайт. Включаю шапку, где у меня колонок в помине нет, даже там где голый row отображается лишь 50%. Чудеса какие-то. Насчёт "col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6" и "col-md-6", изначально второй вариант и юзал. Но из-за этого косяка добавил два первых класса, потому как думал это из-за их отсутствия. Что делать хз...

Comment: @overtheman Можете показать HTML-CSS и/или ссылку на страницу?

Comment: http://uefacups.ru/

Comment: @overtheman На странице полно элементов, не помещающихся на мобильнике по ширине. Обновил ответ.

Comment: гемор эти смартфоны с 360px. Спасибо, за чёткий и точный ответ.